# How to Programmatically Create a Word Document Containing Images on an Android?

Tags: android, ms-word

On an Android, I want to programmatically create a word document (which will contain images) with UTF-8 support.

Actually I am looking for a standard lightweight library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only a few options available:

- [Aspose.Words for Android](http://www.aspose.com/android/word-component.aspx) (reads and creates docs)
- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (poor support)
- [OliveDOCLibrary for Android](https://code.google.com/p/android-office-demo/wiki/OliveDOCLibrary) (only reads)

Your best bet is on Aspose.Words for what you are looking for, but it comes with a price. Other two options are free and open source.

Answer (score 3):

I can't Find Any Library To Work With Word Documents

I used [Itext](http://itextpdf.com/) For Creating PDF files instead of Word Documents

Comment: doctor advised me to eat apples but i eat oranges.. does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but as I had the same problem and was looking for a solution for a long time, I would like to point out these two free options:

https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

This enables you to create a custom Apache POI .jar-file with only the necessary parts of POI for your task, as POI is capable of handling other document types as well.

To enable word support with image handling for the custom jar, you would have to remove the following lines from the build.gradle file in the poishadow folder:

`exclude 'org/apache/poi/wp/**'
exclude 'org/apache/poi/xwpf/**'
exclude 'org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/**'
exclude 'org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/**'`

Then build the project according to the documentation mentioned in the README of the project. This is necessary because the standard POI would not run on Android out of the box because of some not supported dependencies (javax etc.) and number of methods limit.

An alternative would be https://github.com/leonardoanalista/java2word which is also not optimized for Android, but has almost no dependencies and can be
made to run on Android. It is only capable of creating .doc-files, but it is very easy to work with and to customize (A little bit of effort is necessary to support images on Android, to base64-encode them in the Android way.) This solution has some limitations when it comes to files with lots of images, as the files get quite big.

Comment: I upvoted your post which increased your reputation 1100%